# SimpleForm: input_html: { data: { bla: nil } } results in data-bla="nil" Attribute (instead of empty value)

Tags: simple-form

I want to set some data attributes for a SimpleForm input. I retrieve their values using a method which sometimes returns nil.

Oddly, SimpleForm seems to interpret `nil` as `"nil"` (a string) which results in `data-xxx="nil"` instead of `data-xxx=""`.

```
= f.input :person_id, input_html: { data: { 'xxx' => nil } }
```

Is this the expected behavior? This seems wrong to me, because now I always have to check for nil and answer with an empty string, if needed:

```
= f.input :person_id, input_html: { data: { 'xxx' => (nil || '') } }
```

Comment: What versions of Simple Form and Rails are you using?

Comment: `simple_form (2.1.0)` and `rails (3.2.15)`.

Comment: Can't reproduce it with these versions. For me it returns data-xxx="null" that's what it should return.